# Use SED in order to filter a file

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to use SED in order to filter a file and only get the id which is constituted of 3 numbers and the Domain (e.g.: google.com).

Original File:

```
451 [04/Jan/1997:03:35:55 +0100] http://www.netvibes.com
448 [04/Jan/1997:03:36:30 +0100] www.google.com:443
450 [04/Jan/1997:03:36:48 +0100] http://84.55.151.142:8080
452 [04/Jan/1997:03:36:51 +0100] http://127.0.0.1:9010
451 [04/Jan/1997:03:36:55 +0100] http://www.netvibes.com
453 [04/Jan/1997:03:37:10 +0100] api.del.icio.us:443
453 [04/Jan/1997:03:37:33 +0100] api.del.icio.us:443
448 [04/Jan/1997:03:37:34 +0100] www.google.com:443
```

Used SED commands : `sed -e 's/\[[^]]*\]//g' -e 's/http:\/\///g' -e 's/www.//g' -e 's/^.com//g' -e 's/:[0-9]*//g'`

Current Output:

```
451  netvibes.com
448  google.com
450  84.55.151.142
452  127.0.0.1
451  netvibes.com
453  api.del.icio.us
453  api.del.icio.us
448  google.com
```

Wished Output:

```
451 netvibes.com
448 google.com
451 netvibes.com
448 google.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using grep

```
sed ... | grep -F '.com'
```

or

```
sed ... | grep '\.com$'
```

or with `sed -n`, using `p` to print match

```
sed -ne 's/\[[^]]*\]//g;s/http:\/\///g;s/www.//g;s/:[0-9]*//g;/.com$/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Expected you've lost api.del.icio.us in your wish output so:

```
cat testfile | awk '{print $1" "$NF}' | sed -r 's/http\:\/\/*//g;s/www\.//g' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}) [0-9].*/\1 /g' | sed -r 's/[0-9]{3} $//g' | grep -v '^$' | uniq
```

If you needs only *.com domains, get it:

cat testfile | awk '{print $1" "$NF}' | sed -r 's/http://*//g;s/www.//g' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | sed -r 's/([0-9]{1,3}) [0-9].*/\1 /g' | sed -r 's/[0-9]{3} $//g' | grep -v '^$' | grep com | uniq

Answer (score 1):

Here's one in awk:

```
$ awk 'match($NF,/[^\.]+\.[a-z]+($|:)/) {
    print $1,substr($NF,RSTART,RLENGTH-($NF~/:[0-9]+/?1:0))
}' file
451 netvibes.com
448 google.com
451 netvibes.com
453 icio.us
453 icio.us
448 google.com
```

If you want just the .coms, replace `[a-z]+` in the `match` regex with `com`.